# select multiple cells and add separator

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have this column:

```
Reference
ref01
ref02
ref03
```

I want to get each reference and combine it into string with a separator(,) like this expected output:
***'ref01','ref02','ref03'***

by the way, this is my code:

```
 For Each .Item("Reference") In DataGridView1
    RefList = RefList & "'" & .Item("Reference") & "', "
    Next
    MsgBox(RefList.Substring(0, RefList.Length - 2))
```

thank you!

Comment: what is the problem in your code?

Comment: Look at `String.Join`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a `ListOf(String)`... You can loop through the `DataGridView` and get the item you need and add it to the list. Then use `String.Join` to glue them together.

```
Dim strList As New List(Of String)
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
  If Not row.IsNewRow Then
    strList.Add("'" & row.Cells("Reference").Value & "'")    
  End If
Next
If strList.Count > 0 Then
  Dim strRes = String.Join(",", strList.ToArray)
  MsgBox(strRes)
End If
```